# React useEffect cleanup not working when app is reopen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-effect

I'm having a problem with useEffect cleanup it does't work when reopening the app. Here's my code.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let { status, data } = state
    if(status === 200 && isFocused){ setData(data) }
    return () => { if(status === undefined && !isFocused){ clearFields() }}
  }, [state, isFocused])
```

My purpose with this cleanup is that I want to clear all the temporary state when user logs out. I can't find any solution to clear the state because when the another user logs in the components are already rendered that's why I want to clear all the temporary states inside a screen or components. Any idea on this? Thank you.

Comment: useEffect call on component mounting and unmounting. You should have an event when user logout so in that event you can clear states. and in the same way when user login, you should reset states on it. Share your full code so can help you more in that